# Select all mispelled words in Sublime Text at once

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3, spell-check

Is there a way to, when activating the `spellchecking` with <kbd>F6</kbd> then noticing that bunch of red-underlined typos, to select all misspelled words?

Obviously we can't do it with a simple <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. The idea is to select all of them, then either copying to a separate file to examine them or simple deleting all at once.

Answer (score 8):

You can easily create a custom plugin to do this:

1. From the `Tools` menu -> `Developer` -> `New Plugin...` (instructions based on Dev Build 3111. For Stable channel 3103, it is just `Tools` -> `New Plugin...` )
2. Replace the contents of the file with the following:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class SelectAllSpellingErrorsCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        regions = []
        while True:
            self.view.run_command('next_misspelling')
            if self.view.sel()[0] not in regions:
                regions.append(self.view.sel()[0])
            else:
                break
        self.view.sel().clear()
        self.view.sel().add_all(regions)
```

3. Save it in the default directory (which will be your `Packages/User` folder) as something like `spelling.py`
4. Create a custom keybinding to run command `select_all_spelling_errors`

Comment: This was just fantastic, Keith. Does exactly what it was meant to do!

Comment: FYI, for anyone who wants to create and use this plugin without bothering with a key binding, you can just run `view.run_command('select_all_spelling_errors')` from the Console.

Comment: How do I add the command to the command palette?

Answer (score 1):

I used the algorithm to perform it on a [file within 1.500.000](https://github.com/evandrocoan/SublimeTextStudio/blob/3bcb2e3255335ea90c9720b215d8e344e3059f88/MultiLingual%20Dictionary/EN_PT.dic) lines/words within 81.000 misspelled words. This was the profile result:

```
         1.555.756 function calls in 9.196,582 seconds ~2,5 hours

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.077    0.077 9196.582 9196.582 <string>:1(<module>)
        1    6.087    6.087 9196.505 9196.505 select_all_spelling_errors.py:23(findRegions)
   245644    1.042    0.000    1.042    0.000 sublime.py:550(__init__)
   163763    2.559    0.000    2.559    0.000 sublime.py:557(__str__)
   245644    1.357    0.000   15.908    0.000 sublime.py:638(__getitem__)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 sublime.py:659(clear)
    81881    0.611    0.000   56.255    0.001 sublime.py:662(add)
        1    0.385    0.385   56.640   56.640 sublime.py:668(add_all)
    81882    0.884    0.000 9114.968    0.111 sublime.py:829(run_command)
   245646    0.344    0.000    0.344    0.000 sublime.py:832(sel)
        1    0.001    0.001 9196.582 9196.582 {built-in method exec}
    81881    0.071    0.000    0.071    0.000 {built-in method isinstance}
    81882 9114.084    0.111 9114.084    0.111 {built-in method view_run_command}
    81881   55.573    0.001   55.573    0.001 {built-in method view_selection_add_region}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method view_selection_clear}
   245644   13.509    0.000   14.551    0.000 {built-in method view_selection_get}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'values' of 'dict' objects}
```

---

There we may see the culprit which eat almost all the time:

```
81882 9114.084    0.111 9114.084    0.111 {built-in method view_run_command}
```

This was the source code used:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin

import cProfile


class SelectAllSpellingErrorsCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):

    def run(self, edit):

        cProfile.runctx( 'findRegions(self, edit)', globals(), locals() )

def findRegions(self, edit):

    regionsList = []

    while True:

        self.view.run_command('next_misspelling')

        if self.view.sel()[0] not in regionsList:

            regionsList.append( self.view.sel()[0] )

        else:

            break

    self.view.sel().clear()
    self.view.sel().add_all( regionsList )
```